# layout_gravity= "start" is not working in Navigation View

Tags: java, android, xml

layout_gravity attribute is not showing in Navigation View.I want to give the layout_gravity = "start" but it is not showing.

Here is my layout.xml file

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see your Navigation View you must add `tools:openDrawer:"start"` in the `DrawerLayout`. 
This will set your Drawer as visible only in the layout editor, in the app it will be hidden until the user opens it.

Remember also to set the Gravity, the Menu and the Header Layout (if you have one) with

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:menu="@menu/your_menu"
app:headerLayout="@layout/your_header_layout"
```

in your NavigationView.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

add this into drawer `tools:openDrawer="start"`  and  add this into navigation

```
   android:layout_gravity="start"
```

and don't forget to add the menu `app:menu="@menu/menu"`

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and past the below code and adjust it and it will work

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start|left"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
```